# Need help to solve shutdown issue in Ubuntu 13.10 with dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10

I want to have dual boot in my laptop but I face some improper shut down. Here is what all I did.

Day 1:

Installed Ubuntu 13.10
Everything worked like charm except Display's Brightness.
Fixed display with help of google and brightness can now be adjusted accordingly.
ShutDown was working fine at present.

Day 2:

Installed Windows 7 in dual boot but mistakenly after installing only Windows 7 will boot up. Tried everything and then deleted the drive containing ubuntu.

Day 3:

Installed Windows 7 on 60 GiB. Made a 150 GiB partition for Ubuntu and remaining for storing data.
Installed Ubuntu 13.10 on 150 GiB with 1GiB swap. Had to create it as logical in order to have swap area.

But on restart it gave me windows again. But this time I used Easy BCD to make an entry for Ubuntu.
Everything is okay now and it has dual boot but when I select Ubuntu it again asks whether to go for Ubuntu or Windows 7. I don't want this option to come.

Secondly screen is now again not getting dim and battery backup is just 3 hours. Also when I give shut down command the laptop freezes after some dots. If I poweroff using Terminal then too I will get some code and it won't go... I mean it again hangs...